# Error in XML document (2,13)

Tags: c#, xml, debugging, deserialization

This is the ASCII data of an XML document returned by an EWS call and formatted using `(new ASCIIEncoding()).GetString(XmlData)`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<categories default="Alltag" lastSavedSession="3" lastSavedTime="2013-11-21T13:15:18.2751355Z" xmlns="CategoryList.xsd">
    <category name="Lila Kategorie" color="8" keyboardShortcut="0" usageCount="2" lastTimeUsedNotes="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedMail="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsed="2013-11-04T16:54:56.824Z" lastSessionUsed="0" guid="{56d27797-6a5f-4e0a-9e68-54e386b68e3a}" renameOnFirstUse="1" />
    <category name="Gelbe Kategorie" color="3" keyboardShortcut="0" usageCount="2" lastTimeUsedNotes="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedMail="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsed="2013-11-04T16:54:56.824Z" lastSessionUsed="0" guid="{19008ab2-00a6-4149-a531-fd58edb3fc8c}" renameOnFirstUse="1" />
    <category name="Blaue Kategorie" color="7" keyboardShortcut="0" usageCount="6" lastTimeUsedNotes="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2013-11-04T16:58:58.111Z" lastTimeUsedMail="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsed="2013-11-04T16:58:58.111Z" lastSessionUsed="1" guid="{94281f1d-827d-43f5-a4f6-3840e9378932}" renameOnFirstUse="0" />
    <category name="Grüne Kategorie" color="4" keyboardShortcut="0" usageCount="2" lastTimeUsedNotes="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedMail="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsed="2013-11-04T16:54:56.824Z" lastSessionUsed="0" guid="{00ce8d45-4555-47a2-b8b1-2f55d6ff6ccc}" renameOnFirstUse="1" />
    <category name="Orange Kategorie" color="1" keyboardShortcut="0" usageCount="6" lastTimeUsedNotes="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2013-11-04T16:59:01.511Z" lastTimeUsedMail="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsed="2013-11-04T16:59:01.511Z" lastSessionUsed="1" guid="{0b4c0f71-b0cc-4c4e-afd1-99ba9af28ff9}" renameOnFirstUse="0" />
    <category name="SChulung" color="2" keyboardShortcut="0" usageCount="6" lastTimeUsedNotes="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2013-11-12T16:11:01.011Z" lastTimeUsedMail="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsed="2013-11-12T16:11:01.011Z" lastSessionUsed="2" guid="{c5c0a53e-a556-4011-8530-0e8e7ddefc90}" renameOnFirstUse="0" />
    <category name="Alltag" color="0" keyboardShortcut="0" usageCount="5" lastTimeUsedNotes="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedMail="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsed="2013-11-19T13:45:32.627Z" lastSessionUsed="2" guid="{d1d2d16e-10f3-4304-9f94-141016b95ccf}" renameOnFirstUse="0" />
    <category name="Feiertag" color="5" keyboardShortcut="0" usageCount="6" lastTimeUsedNotes="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2013-11-19T13:52:12.467Z" lastTimeUsedMail="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z" lastTimeUsed="2013-11-19T13:52:12.467Z" lastSessionUsed="3" guid="{6e812025-ab62-4092-b599-55df683eef20}" renameOnFirstUse="0" />
</categories>
```

<strike>My first question: What does ??? mean at that point? Is this caused by me using ASCII instead of UTF or whatever encoding MS uses?</strike>

My program, trying to decode aforementioned document, throws an "Error in XML document (2,13)" in the second line of the following:

```
UserConfiguration UsrConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(ews, "CategoryList", WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, UserConfigurationProperties.All);
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(UsrConfig.XmlData);
```

My second question: What does the `(2,13)` mean?

To clarify, I asked the program to return the `BaseException`, it is

```
System.FormatException: GUID muss 32 Ziffern mit 4 Bindestrichen enthalten (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
bei System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
bei System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult& result)
bei System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
bei System.Guid..ctor(String g)
bei System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToGuid(String s)
bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMasterCategoryList.Read5_MasterCategoryList(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMasterCategoryList.Read6_categories()
```

Problem: I don't see any Guid that does not meet these requirements; and even if I did, the XMLs origin is Microsoft - I don't see why I should have to change anything there.

The XML deserialization is done according to a model I found on the net, which contains

```
[XmlAttribute("guid")]
public Guid Id
{
    get { return _IdField; }
    set {
        _IdField = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
    }
}
```

My third question: What other possibilities, than changing the `Guid` data type to `string`, will I have to solve my problem? (By the way, I only need name and color of the categories...)

Comment: Yes, `???<?xml` (the BOM) and `Gr??ne` (`ü`) pretty much indicate you're using an ASCII encoding where the source is Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

[(new UTF8Encoding()).GetString(XmlData)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or

[(new UnicodeEncoding()).GetString(XmlData)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

instead